# Visual studios can not find cuda Error while training on yolo7v

Tags: machine-learning, yolov7

when i try to train on yolo v7 I get this error:

```
File "train.py", line 595, in <module>
    device = select_device(opt.device, batch_size=opt.batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\96Crori\Desktop\yolov7_custom_training\yolov7\utils\torch_utils.py", line 71, in select_device
    assert torch.cuda.is_available(), f'CUDA unavailable, invalid device {device} requested'  # check availability        
AssertionError: CUDA unavailable, invalid device 0 requested
```

I installed cuda version 11.3 but i dont know why visual studios cant find it

Comment: Hello, can you add a tag depicting the language you're using? It is Python, I think. And a piece of code showing us where your problem take place.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the problem. I had the wrong version of Pytorch installed which was not letting me access cuda. Once I installed the correct version the error went away.

Comment: If you do answer your question, make sure you explain properly what your problem was: in this case, what version of PyTorch you had and what PyTorch you installed after that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).